# Telegram bot API custom keyboard - how to make vertical buttons list?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a PHP code

```
$keyboard = [
                'inline_keyboard' => [['text' =>  $name, 'callback_data' => $placeId]],
            ];
                $markup = json_encode($keyboard, true);
                $content = [
                    'chat_id' => $chatId,
                    'reply_markup' => $markup,
                    'text' => 'Here is your places list. Choose one to get map with it.',
                    'disable_notification' => true
                ];
```

And in out of this code I have list of some inline-menu buttons, but this buttons listed inline, horizontal, and text names is cutted like "Text Bu..".

How can I make vertical inline-menu buttons like on example of Telegram docs?
Here is the [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) and image with example

[image: image with example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-'inline_keyboard' => [['text' =>  $name, 'callback_data' => $placeId]],
+'inline_keyboard' => [[['text' =>  $name1, 'callback_data' => $placeId1]], [['text' =>  $name2, 'callback_data' => $placeId2]]],
```